# Use Realsense camera to get the camera image

Tags: cameras, python, lidar

I have to use LIDAR in my project. I was searching for some LIDARs with a camera and came across the [Intel RealSense d400 series](https://www.intelrealsense.com/introducing-intel-realsense-d400-product-family/). I know it has a camera but please suggest a way to use that camera along with getting the distance from the sensor in python.

Comment: what sensor are you talking about? ... you didn't say which LIDAR module you are using

Comment: The exact info I have of it is that it is 82635DSAWGPRQ Intel Realsense Camera. On this site https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/intel-realsense/82635DSAWGPRQ/544-3609-ND/9926008

Comment: I should have said Depth Camera maybe... and the processor is D4

Comment: please edit yur post so that it says what you mean to say